# Excel match will not find true match

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I've encountered a very annoying issue with my excel spreadsheet.

I'm ranking a bunch of values and attaching points to the values based on their rank, but consistently, the lowest value cannot be found by `MATCH`.

Excel recognizes the values as equal when testing `=6=A5` (returns TRUE), but it's driving me crazy that the match function returns NA.

Any help here?

[link to file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5e9j8g4gepgii0s/sample.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Does the *match_type* parameter correspond with your data, ie zero for unordered data?

Comment: Thanks AFH. I didn't assign a match_type. Changing it to 0 solved it. But omitting it should still work for values "that is less than or equal to" - no?

Comment: When you have `match_type` is 1 (or omitted), then Excel suppose your range of data is sorted in ascending order, if not, then return value might not be correct (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

Comment: No. As @MátéJuhász says, telling `MATCH()` that data are sorted when they aren't leads to unpredictable results. Likewise for the `*LOOKUP()` functions. Unsorted data require an exact value match; only sorted data will return the highest value below that sought.